# Redirect to login page when 'Back' button is clicked after log out

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, authorization, outputcache

I am using MVC 3 for my project and my problem is like this:
I would like to have the user redirected to login page when clicking 'back' button after logging out. I am aware that clicking back button will give the user a copy of the previous page stored in the browser's cache. So what I did was to add attributes

```
[Authorize]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
```

to every actionresult or Controller class that needs to authentication first before the intended view is rendered. Solved the problem at first, however complications came when one page(Search results page) requires grid data to be cached in client's browser since it is 'too large' to be fetched every time. Plus, I already have anchor links to the said page, so not allowing cache would render an empty grid.

Is there any way that when a user logs out and tries to go to a 'cached page' through the 'Back' button be routed to the login page first?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way that when a user logs out and tries to go to a
>   'cached page' through the 'Back' button be routed to the login page
>   first?

No, unless you disable browser cache. You don't have control over the browser Back button.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a helper/BaseController.cs which will force the user to the login page if they are not logged in.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Helper
{
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // If session exists
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
        {
            if (this.Session["LoginName"] == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
                return;
            }
        }
        //otherwise continue with action
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
}
```

Then add it to the top off all your contollers i.e:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ShieldUser.Models;
using PagedList;
using Helper;

namespace ShieldUser.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : BaseController
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your javascript file

```js
  // Replace current history state with the login page
function replaceHistoryWithLogin() {
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, '/login'); // Adjust the path if necessary
  }
  
  // Logout function (call this when the user logs out)
  function logout() {
    // Perform logout actions (e.g., clearing session data)
    sessionStorage.clear();
    
    // Replace the current history state with the login page
    replaceHistoryWithLogin();
  }
  
  // Listen for the popstate event (triggered by the back button)
  window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    // If the user tries to navigate back to a restricted page, redirect them to the login page
    if (!isLoginPage()) {
      replaceHistoryWithLogin();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).